# Как распарсить временную зону в DateTimeFormatter?

Tags: java, datetime

У меня есть String такого содержания:

```
2017-05-16T19:33:15+03:00
```

Мне нужно его распарсить в LocalDateTime. Решил делать это при помощи DateTimeFormatter. Паттерн получается такой:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
```

Трудности возникли с зоной. Как её прописать в этом паттерне, чтобы он схавал String?

Альтернативные варианты (не через DateTimeFormatter) приветствуются.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стоит экранировать `T` в серединке: `'T'`. 
Вместе с таймзоной это будет выглядеть примерно так: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[XXX][X]"`

Код:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[XXX][X]");

String date = "2017-05-16T19:33:15+03:00";
System.out.println(dateTimeFormatter.parse(date));
```

Вывод в консоль:

> {OffsetSeconds=10800, InstantSeconds=1494952395},ISO resolved to 2017-05-16T19:33:15

Похожий/аналогичный вопрос: [Java DateTimeFormatter for time zone with an optional colon separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637626/java-datetimeformatter-for-time-zone-with-an-optional-colon-separator/34637904)